# Dojo: FilteringSelect and XSS escaping

Tags: javascript, dojo, xss

I have a web service that returns a json list of filenames. My UI makes an Ajax call to this web service to populate a dojo FilteringSelect. Due to XSS issues I have had to escape the filenames server side such that < filename > becomes & lt; filename & gt; (Spaces added to show the actual chars)

Now in the dojo FilteringSelect I can update the labelType to be "html" and it then displays the filename as expected but when I select that filename, the widget display field shows & lt; filename & gt;

Is there anyway to format the widget display to show < filename > in both the dropdown list and the selected display?

fyi: I am using org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4 to escape the filename list and my dojo widget declaration looks like:

```
new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
    id: "filename_id",
    name: "filename",
    store: fnStore,
    fetchProperties: { sort: {attribute:"id",descending: true} },
    searchAttr: "id",
    labelType: "html",
}, "filename_id");
```

Thanks